# How to check if a number is an integer in Pari/GP?

Tags: if-statement, math, factorial, pari, pari-gp

I'm trying to write an if statement like this

```
 if(denominator([(i-1)! + 1] / i)-1,print(hi),print(ho))
```

`i` can be any integer, for example 10. When I set `i` to 10 it gives this error:

```
? [(x-1)! + 1] / x
  ***   this should be an integer: [(x-1)!+1]/x
                                    ^-----------
```

I really only need to check if `[(x-1)! + 1] / x`  is an integer or not. The denominator thing is what I came up with, I also tried **Mod** but couldn't get that working either.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you are confused with the names `x` and `i`.
Please, see that expression below works properly:

```
i = 10;
print([(i-1)! + 1] / i);
gp > [362881/10]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the error was but I ended up using a floor function for determining if it was an integer or not.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
print(if(((i-1)! + 1) % i, "hi", "ho"))
```

If `i` (in your question `x`) is not an integer, you get an error from the `!` (factorial) operator (but see `gamma` as well).

Do not use `[]` here, it creates a **vector**.

The opreator `%` which I used, gives the remainder. For example `11 % 4` gives the integer `3`. In comparison `Mod(11, 4)` is not an ordinary integer, it is a member of the ring Z/4Z (integers modulo 4). That is very useful in many cases.

I supposed you wanted to write out strings, so I used quotes `"`. If hi and ho are variables, omit the quotes of course.